# Still able to access Document Library even when it's restricted

Tags: document-library, access

I am trying to create a document library which is only restricted to a particular group. I've followed the instructions to the point here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nskBZbBcE70

[image]

Even when I'm not a part of that group, I am still able to upload files in it. Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As site collection admin you have access to every resource in the site collection, even if you break permission inheritance and don't grant access explicitly.

Comment: thanks for your reply. is there a way to bypass this? i just need to create a document library that can only be accessed by a certain user group. is there a way to achieve this on sharepoint?

Comment: Why do you want to bypass this? Only highly privileged and trusted users should be specified as site collection admins, because they can do everything in the site collection. If some user must have high permissions, but he shouldn't have access to some resource, you should give him full control rights instead of site collection admin rights.